# Dynamic Pivot in Sql Syntax Puzzle

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a tables as follows. Table #temp

```
Product     Date      1st Pass Count    2nd Pass Count   3rd Pass Count
A           06-07-2015       2               4              5
A           06-07-2015       3               2              1
B           06-07-2015       1               1              1
```

Now I want a view as follows;

```
Product      06-07-2015   07-07-2015    08-07-2015
    A            17          0             0
    B            3           0             0
```

The date column is a sum of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd pass.

I have tried the query below . 2 problems I need help with.

Problem 1 - More than one row for Product A.
Problem 2 - Cant seem to add all 1st, 2nd and 3rd pass in sql query with pivot. Tried sum ( [1st pass]+[2nd pass]+[3rd pass] ) and it gave a syntax error.

Current code that works before I try things to correct the 2 problems above.

```
DECLARE @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols=STUFF ( SELECT ',' +QUOTENAME(PRODUCT) FROM #TEMP group by DATE ORDER BY DATE FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE).value.('.',NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') set @query='SELECT [PRODUCT],' + @cols + 'from 'Select [PRODUCT],[DATE],[1st Pass],[2nd Pass],[3rd Pass] from #TEMP)x Pivot (sum [1st pass] FOR DTE in ('+@cols+') )p' execute (@query)
```

Is there something obvious I am missing here in terms of solving these last 2 problems ?

Comment: it got little bit but see is that matching your requirement @jameskhan

Answer (score 0):

we can get the above result set by using Pivot and Cross Apply

**Normal Pivot**

```
DECLARE @t  TABLE  (Product Varchar(5),dated varchar(10),firstcount int,secondcount int,thirdcpount int)

INSERT INTO @t (Product,dated,firstcount,secondcount,thirdcpount)values 
 ('A','06-07-2015',2,4,5),
 ('A','06-07-2015',3,2,1),
 ('B','06-07-2015',1,1,1)

select Product,SUM(ISNULL([06-07-2015],0)) As [06-07-2015],SUM(ISNULL([07-07-2015],0))As [07-07-2015],SUM(ISNULL([08-07-2015],0))As [08-07-2015] from (
select Product,dated,COL,val from @t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('firstcount',firstcount),('secondcount',secondcount),('thirdcpount',thirdcpount))CS(COL,val))TT
PIVOT (SUM(VAL) FOR Dated IN ([06-07-2015],[07-07-2015],[08-07-2015]))T
GROUP BY Product
```

And

**by using Dynamic Query Pivot**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
 DROP TABLE #t
GO
CREATE TABLE #t (Product Varchar(5),dated varchar(10),firstcount int,secondcount int,thirdcpount int)

INSERT INTO #t (Product,dated,firstcount,secondcount,thirdcpount)values 
 ('A','06-07-2015',2,4,5),
 ('A','06-07-2015',3,2,1),
 ('B','06-07-2015',1,1,1)
,('A','07-07-2015',2,11,5),
('A','07-07-2015',3,2,1),
('B','07-07-2015',1,1,1)
,('A','08-07-2015',3,11,6),
('A','08-07-2015',1,6,1),
('B','08-07-2015',11,1,6)


DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)
,@columns NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns + ', ', '') + N'[' + tbl.dated + ']'
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT dated
   FROM #t
   ) AS tbl

SELECT @statement = ' select Product,SUM(ISNULL([06-07-2015],0)) As [06-07-2015],SUM(ISNULL([07-07-2015],0))As [07-07-2015],SUM(ISNULL([08-07-2015],0))As [08-07-2015] from (
select Product,dated,COL,val from #t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(''firstcount'',firstcount),(''secondcount'',secondcount),(''thirdcpount'',thirdcpount))CS(COL,val))TT
PIVOT (SUM(VAL) FOR Dated IN (' + @columns + ')) as pvt GROUP BY Product'

EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @statement
```